# What does the #^ operator mean in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

What does `#^` mean in Clojure? My copy of *The Joy of Clojure* doesn't mention this operator anywhere (it's not in the index or anywhere in the text that I've looked). I can't really search for it with Google, because the operator is made up of special characters that the search box ignores.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`#^` is the old form of the metadata [reader macro](http://clojure.org/reader). It was changed to `^` in clojure 1.2.

Comment: Thanks. This is some old Clojure code, and it looks like it's using `#^` all over the place for type-hints for the compiler.